# How can I upload a file to Struts from a standalone Java class?

Tags: java, struts, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am trying to call a Struts action from simple, standalone Java class.

The Struts action uses `FormFile`s to receive file uploads.

I am reading about `URLConnection` and `HttpURLConnection`, but am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I have written client java code,but now server side is giving NullpointerException. I am using FormFile for file upload in the form. and at `theForm.setFileName(theForm.getFiletoupload().getFileName());`  it's throwing NullpoinerException.It works with normal upload. Any idea what is happening..????  or there is problem in client java code..???

Comment: (Consider deleting your follow-up comment; out-of-context it's just confusing, and isn't directly related to this question, but a new one based on an implementation attempt.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general form submission is just an HTTP POST request with parameteres.
It gets generated by your java standalone class and sent to the server, the server proceeds this request and then redirects it to Struts.

However I wouldn't use here directly the low-level java API since it doesn't implement the HTTP protocol.
If putting an additional jar to your project is not an issue, I  suggest you to use 
Apache HTTPClient project
Here is an example (much more simple than it would be with HttpConnection):
[Example](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, Actually I am using IMB-WAS app server,do i need to configure it for using HTTPClient or it's just a matter of client side(Standalone java class)?

Comment: AFAIK - no, its like asking "do I need to configure WAS to be used with  Firefox". Both firefox and HTTPClient are http protocol client implementations. So you can just use your HTTP Client inside your standalone application instead of using directly HTTPUrlConnection. Hope this helps.

Comment: ,That example was of Post method, what do you think about Multipart Post method?

Comment: Well, I've never used the multipart post, I admit :)  But as long as its a part of HTTP standard (I suppose, it will be mapped to a simple HTTP POST with headers) and your server is able to handle these headers  (again, regardless the type of client who issued such a request) everything should work. I think its exactly the point when you should try it out :)

Comment: i have tried code for client using HttpURLConnection and  using Apache HttpClien's both(PostMethod and MultipartPostMethod) methods. But i am getting NullpointerException on struts side which makes use of FormFile. Do you think there is any problem with the use of FormFile?? but it's working properly with simple upload though jsp...

Comment: I've never used FormFile, I barely rememerb struts actually. Is it possible that the Struts framework fails to create a FormFile? If I remmeber correctly it should inject it into the action form. Possibly its because of lack of some Http Header it expects to receive? It should be in Struts, try to understand why exactly you get an NPE.

Comment: Heeyy got it working !! It was silly mistake, 1st arg to FilePart should have been form property name not filename... THANKS for Your comments those were really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your question ... you are creating object of action class (by standalone java class) and want to use it similar as action class works in struts.
But when **you** create object of action class it works as a normal java class instead of struts's action class.
Action class object must be created by struts framework only.

Comment: No, i want to upload a file to struts application from simple java class.